# Is it possible to call the function from the C macro definition in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors, macros, user-defined-functions

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ADD_NUMMBERS numbers_add() /*this is called in the below Marco*/

#define ADDED_NUMBERS (a, b, c)  \
{                                  \
  if(ADD_NUMMBERS)  \
    add_afb(a, b, &c); \
  else                                 \
    add_bfa(a, b, &c); \
}

int numbers_add (int a, int b)
{
    if (a > b)
      return 1;
    else 
      return 0;
}

int add_afb (int a, int b, int *c)
{
    *c = a+b+10;
}

int add_bfa (int a, int b, int *c)
{
    *c = a+b+20;
}


int main()
{
    int a, b, c; 
    printf("\n enter the a and b values");
    scanf("\n %d %d", &a, &b);
    
    ADDED_NUMBERS (a, b, c);  
    return 0;
}
```

> main.c: In function ‘main’: main.c:14:1: error: expected ‘;’ before
> ‘{’ token  {                                  \  ^ main.c:46:5: note:
> in expansion of macro ‘ADDED_NUMBERS’
> ADDED_NUMBERS (a, b, c);

I am getting the above error and could not figure out the problem.
Please any help is appreciated. Also suggest any alternative for this if it is not possible.

Comment: You can stop the compiler after preprocessing, and see what the macro `ADDED_NUMBERS` expanded to in your code. For GCC this is done with the `-E` option.

Comment: You didn't pass any parameters to `numbers_add()`

Comment: As a hint: Spaces in macro definitions are very significant. The macro definition `#define ADDED_NUMBERS (a, b, c)` doesn't do what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing space to function #define ADDED_NUMBERS (a, b, c)

```c
#define ADDED_NUMBERS(a, b, c) \
{                               \
  if(ADD_NUMMBERS(a, b))        \
    add_afb(a, b, &c);          \
  else                          \
    add_bfa(a, b, &c);          \
}
```